# Why don't we have a group_by! in the ruby enumerable module?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Is there a reason why we don't have a group_by! method in the enumerable module. Why do I have to do this:

```
something = something.group_by(&:attr)
```

vs

```
something.group_by!(&:attr)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because group_by can change type of variable (and variable method cannot do it).

For example:

```
something = [1,2,3,4,4] 
# something is Array

something = something.group_by{|x| x % 2 } 
# => {1=>[1, 3], 0=>[2, 4, 4]}
# now something is a Hash
```

Comment: what's the constraint for a method not to be able to return a different type? (They are both ruby objects) Why couldn't ``group_by!`` return a hash instead of an array? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: If `group_by!` just return result (hash) and doesn't modify object - it will be same as `group_by`

Comment: Sorry I meant to say why can't ``group_by!`` modify ``self`` to be the returned value of ``group_by`` ?

Comment: Because it's impossible to modify `self`:
`self = 1` => 
`SyntaxError: (irb):2: Can't change the value of self`